# index seems to be changed during eq

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add a class and remove the on click event for a link when it is clicked and then undo this when another link is clicked, I have an example here http://jsfiddle.net/bdjohnson/zXyb9/4/

But after a few clicks it dies, I output the index to the console and it kept changing, is this the wrong way to do it?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you do not need any `each` loop to attach a click handler.
Just use `click` on a jQuery object will attach event handler to any element of the collection.

Then you can write code way more simple:

```javascript
$(function() {
    var previews = $("#pic div"); // Caching selector
    previews.hide();

    $("a.pic_link").click(function(event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass("active")) {
            previews.slideUp(300).delay(300).eq($this.index()).slideDown(300);
            $this.addClass("active");
            $this.siblings().removeClass("active");
        }
    });
});​
```

Note that you should use `complete` callback instead of using `delay`, like this:

```javascript
previews.slideUp(300, function() {
   previews.eq($this.index()).slideDown(300);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution it works great, but if I replace the slideup delay with the complete callback you suggested I get weird results. Not sure if this is due to the divs being different heights when real pictures are used. Or maybe I used it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need the `active` class and why you need to remove the click event, but here is my solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.pic_link").on("click", function() {
        var i = $(this).index(); //get the index of the clicked link (I assume that the clicked link length is always the same as the #pic div length)
        var d = $("#pic div"); //get the divs for the #pic element
        d.removeClass("active"); //remove the active class on all of the child divs
        if (d.filter(":visible").length > 0 && d.filter(":visible").index() != i) { //if there is a #pic div visible and it is different from the link that is clicked, then hide it and then show the proper one and add the class
            d.filter(":visible").slideUp(300, function() {
                d.eq(i).addClass("active").slideDown(300, function() {});
            });
        }
        else {
            d.eq(i).addClass("active").slideDown(300, function() {});//just add the class and show the proper element
        }
    });
});​
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zXyb9/25/)

In addition, I would suggest that you use CSS to initially hide the `#pic div`'s, otherwise there may be a flicker of the `#pic div`'s showing up. It is in the jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the code,the active class is so the chosen link can be styled/set as selected, and I just thought setting it to hidden in the css would make it more difficult for any with out JavaScript to see the images.

Comment: Why not just style all of the `div`'s and not change the class? This will work since you are only displaying one at a time. Just a thought. Good luck with your coding!